# Android - passing field name as selectionArgs to rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm passing the below statement as a rawQuery in Android:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ltUsers._id,ltUsers.NAME,ltUsers.GLOBAL_ID, ltGroups.GROUP_NAME
        FROM ltUsers
        JOIN ltGroups ON (ltUsers.GROUP_ID = ltGroups.GLOBAL_ID)    
        WHERE ltgroups.GLOBAL_ID = ? " +
        ORDER BY ltUsers.NAME ASC,ltgroups.GLOBAL_ID ASC;
```

With the rawQuery as follows:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,args)
```

It works just fine if I pass a value to the parameter, e.g.

```
String[] args = new String[]{"2"}
```

However, I also want to be able to show all rows, unlimited by the `GLOBAL_ID` in the `WHERE` clause. Testing on a dump of my SQLite database outside of Android - as well as in Android by just writing the parameter directly into the statement - shows the following clause to be a valid way to do this:

```
WHERE ltGroups.GLOBAL_ID = ltGroups.GLOBAL_ID
```

Yet when I pass the field reference `ltGroups.GLOBAL_ID` or `[ltGroups].[GLOBAL_ID]` as a parameter it fails to return any rows in the rawQuery. Any ideas on why this might be happening? Happy to produce any extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters always replace specific values, not anything else.

When you put the string "`ltGroups.GLOBAL_ID`" into the parameters array, it is interpreted as exactly that, a string.

(To show all records, just omit the `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: Thanks for that, it's as I suspected. Just means I've had to do something fiddly, putting in a conditional to run different SQL when all rows are requested.